# max-width doesn't work with long words

Tags: css, word-wrap

I have a div with paragraphs. I'd like to set a max-width. It works, the problem is that long words don't wrap...

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/multiformeingegno/s8qE3/

```
<div style="max-width:100px">
<p>Something Something! BASTAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA!!!!!<br/>
```

Comment: Have you tried adding this code: `word-break:break-all;` to the div?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can apply the following CSS code:

```
p {
    word-wrap:break-word
}
```

This will cause your paragraphs to wrap on words.

Answer (score 2):

Add `word-wrap` to your CSS:

```
p{ word-wrap: break-word; }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/fmpeyton/bH2Ne/